# Using a rented VPS as an Openvpn server for friends: legal risks and how to avoid them?

Tags: linux, openvpn, vps

**Disclaimer**: I **have** done some research on the legal implications of an Openvpn server hosted on a VPS, but have come back from these quite empty-handed.

**Context**: We are a bunch of friends in engineering, and all live on the same campus. The Internet connection there is filtered to drop all non-80/443 TCP and mail packets. I have contacted our network administrator, and he just said that this was to minimize security risks and to limit bandwidth usage by not allowing any kind of torrenting. Since people still download like madmen on web sharing platforms, doesn't seem to work that well, but this is not the subject.
In any case, I asked him his stance on VPNs, and he stated that he isn't against the use of bandwidth-limited VPNs on the school network..

In order to provide my friends with a way to play online games (League, Hearthstone, etc.), I'm currently renting a cheap 100 mbps OVH VPS acting as an Openvpn server. Using Linux's Traffic Control, I am limiting each client's bandwidth to 1 mo/s maximum, and the administrator is okay with that. Bandwidth usage is currently being logged using Bandwidthd.

**I'm wondering**: what are the legal issues I could be faced with if one of the users of my VPN downloads torrents and gets caught? Would keeping all packet logs between each of my clients and the world be enough to keep me from trouble? If not, what would you recommend?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not a soul to come to my help ? :(